# How to install cygwin using chocolatey to specific directory?

Tags: cygwin, chocolatey

I am using chocolatey(community version) to install cygwin.  This get installed to

> c:\tools\cygwin

I would like to configure cygwin to be at **c:\cygwin**.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variable `ChocolateyBinRoot` to `C:\`. In newer versions of Chocolatey ([v0.9.10+](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/631)) this is now called `ChocolateyToolsLocation`.

Read Chocolatey docs for more information: https://chocolatey.org/docs/getting-started#where-are-chocolatey-packages-installed-to

Comment: It's now called `ChocolateyToolsLocation`